# Can a polynomial trend line be extended to project future data as in lofting a boat?

Tags: time-series

I often run into charts of data projecting expectations that a rate of increase will continue at an increasing rate.

http://arctic-news.blogspot.com/

Is it legit to include in a graph a range of expectations modeled by different geometric and arithmetric series as a polynomial trend line?

Take for example the IPCC projections of sea level rise globally, in the northern hemisphere, and in the arctic sampled approximately every five years.

1990 1 mm/yr
1995 1 mm/yr
2000 2 mm/yr
2005 3 mm/yr
2010 5 mm/yr
2015 8 mm/yr
2020 13mm/yr
...
if recognized as the Fibonacci series could this reasonably be compared to actual data from regions with different rates of SLR, and if so  how far into the future?

I know that if I use a CAD program such as AutoCad to draw a Polyline, Nurb or Spline or Excel to fit curve a modeled projection to data as if I were trying to loft a boat with a thin strip of wood and three nails, its difficult to bend the line at one end and stay on the data points at the other only for a few increments and yet the resultant fair curve produces better results than a linear projection certainly.

Answer (score 0):

most likely not, neither can a spline or nurb. While linear and quadratic models can tell you about the direction it is going to go in the future, higher models are not stable outside of the range of your datapoints.

You can do something like this with Gaussian Processes, which will also give you confidence bounds. Here is a good book, which can be downloaded: http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/

However, you must realize that the example you give is one that might not fit here. After all, the things you describe lie in the field of Meteorology where they have a lot of nice and complex models to do what you want to do. :)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I know that when I'm doing animation I can interpolate between points, and I can add points anywhere the curve gets tight to smooth it, I can move along x,y, and z coordinates and change lighting, shadowing, and texture mapping while rotating inside a nurb and collecting different reflections and degrees of transparency

Comment: I have just read the first two chapters of your link. It is exactly the sort of reference I was looking for. It makes me want to go back and reread Graphic Kernal Systems with Breshnehan's line and circle algorthym for choosing pixels. Thanks!

Comment: If you like it so much, you should probably mark the question as answered. ;)